# ms crm 2011 solutions

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, solution

Assuming I received a managed solution from another developer which contains an amended contact entity. How should I best make changes to that entity without affecting theirs'?

The changes would be additions as opposed removing anything they have done but ultimately for the end user I want them to see a mix of their original contact entity plus my changes. Is it best I simply create a new unmanaged solution, add their existing contact entity and make changes that way? Or do I start afresh adding in the contact entity from the system layer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with these solutions internally in your organization you should almost always use an unmanaged solution.  Managed solutions are for the most part a way to box your CRM customizations in order to sell them and protect them from being changed.  If this is the case you are dealing with you can probably still amend the entity but you would have to do it in the default solution or another solution - sounds like you are already going down this track.  I haven't tested importing a managed solution and changing an entity customization but this is how I would expect it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the best option is to create managed solutions will which will not override the existing customizations but it will add any extra customization without affecting the existing ones.

You should use managed solutions only when you want to have the feature to install or an uninstall changed you have imported.

Answer (score 0):

Only if the 'Customization' field for the amended contact entity is set to true, you can directly modify the update and include your changes there. Otherwise, you can create your own managed solution that has the contact entity modifications and import it to your system. Dynamics CRM will then merge your changes with the other ones.